# jQuery Parsing JSON Objects and Array

Tags: jquery, json, each, arrays

In the following code:

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'accounts', 'action'=>'get_customers_order_mcs')); ?>/'+customer_order_id,
                function(data){
                    var json_mc = data.MasterCarton.mc;
                    alert(json_mc);
                    $.each(json_mc,function(){
                         console.log(this);
                   });
             });
```

The data sent as response is as follows-

```
{
     "MasterCarton":{
                         "id":"40",
                         "mc":"[
                                    "1":{\"mc_number\":\"Warehouse1\\\/2013-2014\\\/CO\\\/ABC Corp\\\/239\\\/101-Red-1\",\"config\":{\"S2\":10,\"S1\":10},\"delivered\":0},            "2":{\"mc_number\":\"Warehouse1\\\/2013-2014\\\/CO\\\/ABC Corp\\\/239\\\/101-Red-2\",\"config\":{\"S2\":10,\"S1\":10},\"delivered\":0},                  "3":{\"mc_number\":\"Warehouse1\\\/2013-2014\\\/CO\\\/ABC Corp\\\/239\\\/104-Black-3\",\"config\":{\"S1\":7,\"S2\":7,\"S5\":6},\"delivered\":0},               "4":{\"mc_number\":\"Warehouse1\\\/2013-2014\\\/CO\\\/ABC Corp\\\/239\\\/104-Black-4\",\"config\":{\"S1\":7,\"S2\":7,\"S5\":6},\"delivered\":0},              "5":{\"mc_number\":\"Warehouse1\\\/2013-2014\\\/CO\\\/ABC Corp\\\/239\\\/104-Black-5\",\"config\":{\"S1\":6,\"S2\":6,\"S5\":7},\"delivered\":0}
                               ]",
                         "delivery_note_id":"0",
                         "customer_order_id":"314"
                 }
}
```

The json array inside of mc is as shown below-

```
[
   "1":{
      "mc_number":"Warehouse1\/2013-2014\/CO\/ABC Corp\/239\/101-Red-1",
      "config":{
         "S2":10,
         "S1":10
      },
      "delivered":0
   },
   "2":{
      "mc_number":"Warehouse1\/2013-2014\/CO\/ABC Corp\/239\/101-Red-2",
      "config":{
         "S2":10,
         "S1":10
      },
      "delivered":0
   },
   "3":{
      "mc_number":"Warehouse1\/2013-2014\/CO\/ABC Corp\/239\/104-Black-5",
      "config":{
         "S1":6,
         "S2":6,
         "S5":7
      },
      "delivered":0
   }
]
```

I am trying to parse each object in it using jquery, and each object is as follows-

```
    {
   "mc_number":"Warehouse1\/2013-2014\/CO\/ABC Corp\/239\/101-Red-1",
   "config":{
      "S2":10,
      "S1":10
   },
   "delivered":0
}
```

To get the above object I using the following jquery code-

```
$.each(json_mc,function(){
       // What should the code be so as to get each individual objects.         
});
```

That is each and every time of .each should get me-

```
   {
      "mc_number":"Warehouse1\/2013-2014\/CO\/ABC Corp\/239\/101-Red-1",
      "config":{
         "S2":10,
         "S1":10
      },
      "delivered":0
   }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're after is simply `this` which is set at every iteration:

```
$.each(json_mc,function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

**Update**

Given the raw response you've shown, you may need to decode it one more time:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(json_mc), function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer jack but when i tried with your solution I am getting [, {, ", m, c ........... so on. So can you plese suggest me the way in which the whole object from { to } is obtained.

Comment: @GaneshYoganand It works fine [here](http://jsbin.com/uwijan/1/). The results you're getting could be due to code that you haven't shown.

Comment: I am getting the log like this. String { 0= "m" } add_sales_invoice (line 294) String { 0= "c" } add_sales_invoice (line 294) String { 0= "_" } add_sales_invoice (line 294) String { 0= "n" }

Comment: @GaneshYoganand You will have to share some of that code, I have no idea what you're doing with the data.

Comment: Jack please look at the question I have edited. I need each objects of mc. What can I do?